# Error 403 Create Online Meeting with Microsoft Graph and the permissions are right

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create online meeting to get the join URL from Microsoft Team Meeting using Postman,but I am getting Forbidden (403) error even after I had provided Application (With Admin Consent) and delegation permission to "OnlineMeetings.Read.All", "OnlineMeetings.Read", "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All", "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite".

PS: I'm using acess token that I generated in Postman and this the same token I can create events to Outlook using Microsoft Graph

Some pictures about the issue:

Azure Application permission
[image: Azure Application permission]

Postman Token Generate that I'm using
[image: Postman Token Generate that I'm using]

The Issue - 403
[image: The Issue - 403]

A Event that I created with the same token (Outlook)
[image: A Event that I created with the same token (Outlook)]

Could Somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The permission required for creating online meeting is `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite` Delegated permission based on [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

I can see that you have added this permission into your Azure AD app from your first screenshot. But you didn't do the consent for it. In this case the permission won't be included in your access token. You can decode your token in https://jwt.io to verify it.

[image]

So please click on "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}" to do the consent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until a fellow user reminded me of an important note. According to Microsoft, you have to use the Skype for Business PowerShell to create a policy for your AppId and then grant that policy per specific user on behalf of which you will want to book an Online Meeting.

[Documentation for creating and granting the policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy)

[Referenced SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822735/how-to-properly-create-an-online-meeting-with-micosoft-graph-v1-0-with-applicati)