# 403 Forbidden returned while creating Online Meeting with Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-teams

Myriad of questions has been asked regarding the Forbidden 403 returned while creating OnlineMeetings with Graph API.

Would anyone please help out here as I am behind delivery.

Code screenshot:

[image: Below is a screenshot of my C# code]

Error returned:

[image: Error Returned]

When I clicked on "Show raw exception details", it showed this below

[image: Show raw exception details]

API Permission on Azure Active Directory for a licensed office 365 account is attached below

[image: API Permission]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you added delegated permissions to app registration. But you are trying to implement [application permissions](https://msteamssubba.blogspot.com/2021/03/graph-api-difference-between-delegated.html) in code.

And also refer below issue: [How to properly create an Online Meeting with Micosoft Graph v1.0 with Application permission? I'm getting a Forbidden response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822735/how-to-properly-create-an-online-meeting-with-micosoft-graph-v1-0-with-applicati/66827486#66827486)

Comment: You may ask question here

Comment: After creating meeting, Microsoft Teams App tells participants to wait for organizer's permission. Is there a way I can allow participants without organizer's permission?